# How to I get my table with multiple multicolumns and mulitrows to fit the page width?

Tags: tables, width

I have a latex table which has multiple multirows and multicolumns, which currently looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, in the description column, the cells do not expand vertically to fit the text, but instead everything is crammed into two vertical cells. How to make this work?

Below is the latex code for the table I currently have. I tried to use tabularx and adjustbox (to rotate the table 90 degrees) but both options still kept my problem

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{report}   

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[]\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{p} &
  \textbf{d} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}f\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{n} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{u} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{f} &
  \textbf{a} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}s\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{7} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CAO\_SUS$\vert$ACA$\vert$WLH, \\ ACA$\vert$OCA$\vert$WLD, \\ OCA$\vert$CAO\_ABO$\vert$WLD\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
   &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$WLD, \\ VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00029} &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
   &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{12} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}VAP\_SUS$\vert$OAC$\vert$BEN, \\ OAC$\vert$PEN$\vert$BAT, \\ PEN$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$BAT\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
   &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{25} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$DEL, \\ VAP\_ABO$\vert$CIP\_SCH$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_SCH$\vert$CIP\_STA$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_STA$\vert$INC$\vert$BAT, \\ INC$\vert$CIP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_SUS$\vert$CIP\_RES$\vert$BST\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  392 &
  356 &
  36 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,44782} &
  19 &
  285 &
  88 &
  37d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  8.838 &
  7.912 &
  926 &
   &
  1.533 &
  5.653 &
  1.652 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{11} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, \\ VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,01476} &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
   &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: not directly related to your question but the markup here is over complictaed you don't need to put every cell in a multicolumn, `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{no}` can be simplified to `no`

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. From the screenshot you added, I guess your table is also too wide for its page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you show an example of how to do this? I got this code be entering my table in an online latex generator

Comment: @leandriis I added the requested information. Could you please write an answer on how to solve this? Then I will accept

Comment: On several occasions the title is wider than the data.  You already use multiple lines for "follow pattern" and "p-value success".  You may need to use abbreviations, or rotate the titles $90^\circ$.

Comment: I guerssed you used that tablegenerator site Its output gets posted from time to time, Literally you can delete every `\multicolumn{1}`  that is specifying the default column layout (that is almost all of them) also `\begin{table}[]` if taken literally means "do not allow this table anywhere" latex catches that case and makes a warning but treats it as `\begin{table}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried making each column header only one symbol, and even changed the text size to tiny, but even then the content of the description column won't spread over more than 2 rows vertically and is still crammed and ugly

Comment: In that case you may need to think about using landscape or breaking the table into two, possibly split over two pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just edited that in

Comment: @JohnKormylo even with landscaping this problem stays. Is there no way of giving the cells in the description column a standard height of 4 rows vertically or so?

Comment: Hi, do You have Your table in .csv file if yes or even not You can use this site for making tables in latex a bit easier https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: @peter - Sorry, just noticed the height/overlap problem.  I sort of fixed it by using \multirow{6} and adding more \\.  Will try playing with \arraystretch.

Comment: If an overly wide table does not want to fit onto a page using either portrait or landscape pages, it is probably time to consider redesigning the table. You could for example remove the entire "description" column and place the corresponding information below the table, probably using tablenotes from the threeparttable package?

Comment: @JohnKormylo but I only commented on `\multicolum` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more alternatives:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{report}   

\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%% Used in example 1 and 2 %%%%%
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize}


%%%%% Only used in example 2 %%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%% Only used in example 3 %%%%%
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{pattern}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{follow \\ pattern}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{nr\\ cases}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{success}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{time}\\ 
\cline{4-11}
 &
 &
 &
\thead{succ} &
\thead{unsucc} &
\thead{p- \\ value} &
\thead{fast} &
\thead{avg} &
\thead{slow} &
\thead{slow \\ (med)} &
\thead{p-\\ value} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{7\tnote{a}} &
  yes &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
   &
  no &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
   &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10\tnote{b}} &
  yes &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00029} &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
   &
  no &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
   &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{12\tnote{c}} &
  yes &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
   &
  no &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
   &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{25\tnote{d}} &
  yes &
  392 &
  356 &
  36 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,44782} &
  19 &
  285 &
  88 &
  37d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
   &
  no &
  8.838 &
  7.912 &
  926 &
   &
  1.533 &
  5.653 &
  1.652 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{11\tnote{e}} &
  yes &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,01476} &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
   &
  no &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
   &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes} \raggedright\scriptsize
\item[a]  CAO\_SUS$\vert$ACA$\vert$WLH, ACA$\vert$OCA$\vert$WLD, OCA$\vert$CAO\_ABO$\vert$WLD
\item[b]  RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$WLD, VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL
\item[c]  VAP\_SUS$\vert$OAC$\vert$BEN, OAC$\vert$PEN$\vert$BAT,  PEN$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$BAT
\item[d]  VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$DEL, VAP\_ABO$\vert$CIP\_SCH$\vert$BAT, CIP\_SCH$\vert$CIP\_STA$\vert$BAT, CIP\_STA$\vert$INC$\vert$BAT, INC$\vert$CIP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, CIP\_SUS$\vert$CIP\_RES$\vert$BST
\item[e]  RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{11}{l}}
\toprule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{success}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{time}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){4-6} \cmidrule(l){7-11}
\thead{pattern} &
\thead{follow \\ pattern} &
\thead{nr\\ cases} & 
\thead{succ} &
\thead{unsucc} &
\thead{p- \\ value} &
\thead{fast} &
\thead{avg} &
\thead{slow} &
\thead{slow \\ (med)} &
\thead{p-\\ value} \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{7\tnote{a}} &
  yes &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  1,0 &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d &
  0,00049 \\
   &
  no &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
   &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d &
   \\ \addlinespace
10\tnote{b} &
  yes &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  0,00029 &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d &
  0,00049 \\
   &
  no &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
   &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d &
   \\ \addlinespace
12\tnote{c} &
  yes &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  1,0 &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d &
  0,00049 \\
   &
  no &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
   &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d &
   \\ \addlinespace
25\tnote{d} &
  yes &
  392 &
  356 &
  36 &
  0,44782 &
  19 &
  285 &
  88 &
  37d &
  0,00049 \\
   &
  no &
  8.838 &
  7.912 &
  926 &
   &
  1.533 &
  5.653 &
  1.652 &
  39d &
   \\ \addlinespace
11\tnote{e} &
  yes &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  0,01476 &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d &
  0,00049 \\ 
   &
  no &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
   &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d &
   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes} \raggedright\scriptsize
\item[a]  CAO\_SUS$\vert$ACA$\vert$WLH, ACA$\vert$OCA$\vert$WLD, OCA$\vert$CAO\_ABO$\vert$WLD
\item[b]  RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$WLD, VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL
\item[c]  VAP\_SUS$\vert$OAC$\vert$BEN, OAC$\vert$PEN$\vert$BAT,  PEN$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$BAT
\item[d]  VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$DEL, VAP\_ABO$\vert$CIP\_SCH$\vert$BAT, CIP\_SCH$\vert$CIP\_STA$\vert$BAT, CIP\_STA$\vert$INC$\vert$BAT, INC$\vert$CIP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, CIP\_SUS$\vert$CIP\_RES$\vert$BST
\item[e]  RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{colspec={cX*{11}{l}},
             hlines, vlines, 
             vspan=even, 
             row{1}={c, m, font=\scriptsize\bfseries}}
pattern &
description & 
{follow \\ pattern} &
{nr\\ cases} & 
succ &
unsucc &
{p- \\ value \\ success} &
fast &
avg &
slow &
{slow \\ (med)} &
{p-\\ value\\ time} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{7} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{CAO\_SUS$\vert$ACA$\vert$WLH, ACA$\vert$OCA$\vert$WLD, OCA$\vert$CAO\_ABO$\vert$WLD} &
  yes &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\
 &
   &
  no &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
   &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d &
   \\
\multirow{2}{*}{10} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$WLD,  VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL} &
  yes &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00029} &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ 
 &
   &
  no &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
   &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d &
   \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{12} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{VAP\_SUS$\vert$OAC$\vert$BEN, OAC$\vert$PEN$\vert$BAT,  PEN$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$BAT} &
  yes &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\
 &
   &
  no &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
   &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d &
   \\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{25} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$DEL,  VAP\_ABO$\vert$CIP\_SCH$\vert$BAT,  CIP\_SCH$\vert$CIP\_STA$\vert$BAT,  CIP\_STA$\vert$INC$\vert$BAT,  INC$\vert$CIP\_SUS$\vert$BAT,  CIP\_SUS$\vert$CIP\_RES$\vert$BST} &
  yes &
  392 &
  356 &
  36 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,44782} &
  19 &
  285 &
  88 &
  37d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ 
 &
   &
  no &
  8.838 &
  7.912 &
  926 &
   &
  1.533 &
  5.653 &
  1.652 &
  39d &
   \\
\multirow{2}{*}{11} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$BAT,  VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL} &
  yes &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,01476} &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\
 &
   &
  no &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
   &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d &
   \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you move things around a bit you may make it fit even without landscape.
I didn't pay too much attention to the meaning here so this layout may not be ideal but something similar is most likely possible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}   

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    %\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    %\usepackage{lscape}% compativility
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}\def\arraystretch{2}
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\footnotesize\scshape}l|l|l|l|l|l||l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{p} &
  \textbf{d} &
  \textbf{f} &
  \textbf{n} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{u} &
  \textbf{f} &
  \textbf{a} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{s} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{7} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\scshape\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}cao\_sus$\vert$aca$\vert$wlh, \\ aca$\vert$oca$\vert$wld, \\ oca$\vert$cao\_abo$\vert$wld\end{tabular}} &
  Y &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d
  \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
 &
   &
  N &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d \\  \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
  &&p&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{1,0} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{0,00049}
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\scshape\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ret$\vert$vap\_sus$\vert$wld, \\ vap\_sus$\vert$vap\_res$\vert$del\end{tabular}} &
  Y &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d 
  \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
 &
   &
  N &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d  \\  \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
  &&p&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{0,00029} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{0,00049} 
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{12} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\scshape\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}vap\_sus$\vert$oac$\vert$ben, \\ oac$\vert$pen$\vert$bat, \\ pen$\vert$vap\_abo$\vert$BAT\end{tabular}} &
  Y &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d 
  \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
 &
   &
  N &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d  \\  \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
  &&p&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{1,0} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{0,00049}
   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{25} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\scshape\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}vap\_sus$\vert$vap\_abo$\vert$del, \\ vap\_abo$\vert$cip\_sch$\vert$bat, \\ cip\_sch$\vert$cip\_sta$\vert$bat, \\ cip\_sta$\vert$inc$\vert$bat, \\ inc$\vert$cip\_sus$\vert$bat, \\ cip\_sus$\vert$cip\_res$\vert$bst\end{tabular}} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{Y} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{392} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{356} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{36} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{19} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{285} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{88} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{37d} 
   \\\cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
 &
   &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{N} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{8.838} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{7.912} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{926} &

  \multirow{1.5}{*}{1.533} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{5.653} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{1.652} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{39d}  \\  \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
  &&p&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{0,44782} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{0,00049}
 \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{11} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\scshape\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}ret$\vert$vap\_sus$\vert$bat, \\ vap\_sus$\vert$vap\_res$\vert$del\end{tabular}} &
  Y &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d 
  \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
 &
   &
  N &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d  \\  \cline{3-6} \cline{7-10}
  &&p&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{0,01476} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{0,00049}
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(I stole John's answer as staring point)

Answer (score 2):

This fits the page (barely).

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{report}   

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    %\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    %\usepackage{lscape}% compativility
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

    \begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable}\def\arraystretch{2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{p} &
  \textbf{d} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}f\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{n} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{u} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{f} &
  \textbf{a} &
  \textbf{s} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}s\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{7} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CAO\_SUS$\vert$ACA$\vert$WLH, \\ ACA$\vert$OCA$\vert$WLD, \\ OCA$\vert$CAO\_ABO$\vert$WLD\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  390 &
  0 &
  390 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  0 &
  0 &
  390 &
  32d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  7.174 &
  0 &
  7.174 &
   &
  738 &
  288 &
  6.148 &
  32d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{10} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$WLD, \\ VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  930 &
  666 &
  264 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00029} &
  99 &
  693 &
  138 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  9.049 &
  6.969 &
  2.080 &
   &
  1.722 &
  5.907 &
  1.420 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{12} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}VAP\_SUS$\vert$OAC$\vert$BEN, \\ OAC$\vert$PEN$\vert$BAT, \\ PEN$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$BAT\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  1.031 &
  1.031 &
  0 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{1,0} &
  214 &
  710 &
  107 &
  38,5d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  7.643 &
  7.643 &
  0 &
   &
  2.406 &
  4.631 &
  607 &
  38d &
   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{25} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_ABO$\vert$DEL, \\ VAP\_ABO$\vert$CIP\_SCH$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_SCH$\vert$CIP\_STA$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_STA$\vert$INC$\vert$BAT, \\ INC$\vert$CIP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, \\ CIP\_SUS$\vert$CIP\_RES$\vert$BST\end{tabular}} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{yes} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{392} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{356} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{36} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{0,44782} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{19} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{285} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{88} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{37d} &
  \multirow{3}{*}{0,00049} \\[\normalbaselineskip] \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{no} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{8.838} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{7.912} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{926} &
   &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{1.533} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{5.653} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{1.652} &
  \multirow{1.5}{*}{39d} &
 \\[\normalbaselineskip] \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{11} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\def\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}RET$\vert$VAP\_SUS$\vert$BAT, \\ VAP\_SUS$\vert$VAP\_RES$\vert$DEL\end{tabular}} &
  yes &
  1.075 &
  790 &
  285 &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,01476} &
  92 &
  799 &
  184 &
  39d &
  \multirow{2}{*}{0,00049} \\ \cline{3-6} \cline{8-11}
 &
   &
  no &
  8.904 &
  6.845 &
  2.059 &
   &
  1729 &
  5.801 &
  1.374 &
  39d &
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistics on a selection of frequent patterns}
\label{tab:patterns-statistics}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much!